# Get the first move in the shortest path - 2d array - java

Tags: java, arrays

I have a 2d array (assume like the one below):

```
#....#.#
####.###
.....#.#
##..#.##

# = obstacle and . = empty
```

I have been able to calculate the shortest path from one point in the maze to another. However, instead of doing this, I would only like to get the first move of this calculated shortest path.

Is there a better way to do this rather than having to recalculate the whole shortest path again and again....

I am comfortable switching between a*, dijkstra and bfs.

Any suggests would be appreciated.

Comment: Can't you just calculate the path once, and then follow that path?

Comment: The start and end points of this shortest path are game objects. Therefore, these both game objects are moving in a constant direction. So every second, i have to recalculate the path and make the first move on the path...

Answer (score 0):

You can try to guess which of the available moves would get you closer to the end point using some heuristics. However, if you want to get the first move of the absolute shortest path, you have to calculate the whole path. You can try to use some memoization to improve your performance.

Comment: could you give me some psuedocode or etc to help me get started for " guess which of the available moves would get you closer to the end point using some heuristics" and what are heuristics??

Comment: A* algorithm includes heuristics that estimates the cost of the cheapest path to the goal. You can start there.